# How does Hibernate map to Postgresql table?

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate

I am wondering how Hibernate communicates with the PostgreSQL database and the table to perform CRUD operations. In short, how are the variables I create, such as 'String eventName' , 'String location' , etc. mapped to a table in PostgreSQL that also has the fields eventName, location, etc.

I read somewhere that you should keep the field names in both the model class with the @Entity the same as the column fields in PostgreSQL. Can anyone confirm this, and if it is the case let me know why (I presume so that it is for easy cross-reference and this is how Hibernate knows which field to connect).

A very detailed explanation that entails more than what I asked for, going through code, is welcomed!

Explaining @Entity, @Table, etc whatever you need :)

Comment: You're asking "how does Hibernate work?" but that's not something that can be easily answered. The simple answer is that you provide the mapping between your database tables/columns and Java classes/properties, and Hibernate uses that information to generate queries for you. The mappings are defined through configuration files or annotations. But presumably you read the docs and know that much. It would help if you narrowed to scope of your question.

Comment: Under the hood hibernate is generating plain old SQL commands to communicate with the DB. When you're "inserting" a pojo for example the magic of hibernate turns the values in the member variables into VALUES of the INSERT statement.

Comment: So then that is why the member variables have to be the same as the table column names because they are being used for INSERT statements... I see. Then @Entity(name='table name') is then used to identify the table in the database